# ASP.net web api 2 error "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have routes configured like this:

```
   routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi2", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
```

And My controller looks like this:

```
  public class RoutineController : ApiController
{
    private readonly RoutineService _routineService;

    public RoutineController(RoutineService routineService)
    {
        _routineService = routineService;
    }



    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("Tags")]
    public List<RoutineTag> Tags()
    {
        return _routineService.GetAllTags();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("SingleRoutine")]
    // GET api/routine/5
    public RoutineViewModel SingleRoutine(int id)
    {
        return _routineService.GetRoutineById(id);

    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
{"Message":"The request is invalid.","MessageDetail":"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'Infrastructure.Api.Models.RoutineViewModel Routine(Int32)' in 'Infrastructure.Api.Controllers.RoutineController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."}
```

If I change method SingleRoutine to this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("SingleRoutine")]
    // GET api/routine/5
    public RoutineViewModel SingleRoutine(int? id)
    {
        if (!id.HasValue)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return _routineService.GetRoutineById((int) id);
}
```

In browser I just see "null".

Why is this happening ?

**EDIT**

This error is shown when I type /api/routine/tags

Comment: At what line does the error occur? I bet it is not in here.

Comment: Exception is not thrown, this error is shown in browser

Comment: And I don't know if it matters but I'm using Niject as IoC

Comment: What is the url you are calling the controller with? Try "api/routine/SingleRoutine/5".

Comment: What is the request which generates this error?  Where is the `id` value in that request?

Comment: @v.shashenko if I type that url it works fine

Comment: @David I've forgot to type that, sorry, I've edited my answer

Comment: @hyperN: If a request for `/api/routine/tags` is routing to `RoutineController.SingleRoutine()` then there's something *very* broken with your routing...

Comment: Yes, that's happening, but I don't know how to change my routing to fix it

Comment: I have tried your code and it works as you expect. For http://localhost:60895/api/routine/tags the Tags action gets called.

Comment: Thanks, maybe something else bothers web api :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this was problem in WebApiConfig I have these lines:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
            );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("CustomApi", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
            );
```

And in Route Config

```
 routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi2", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
```

Now  in WebApiConfig I have:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("CustomApi", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
         );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
            );
```

And In RouteConfig:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Default",
             url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
         );
```

And it works!

Comment: Please include this in update for your question. All this information you should have provided with your question.

Comment: @Guanxi But this is solution, now it works, why should I put it in Question ?

Answer (score 1):

for api/{controller}/{action}/{id} route URL api/routine/5 search for function (action) 5 which is not there

**Update:**

your error message has the reason why it is failing : **An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter."}**

int is not nullable so when you don't supply its value, it fails to create id.

Comment: I've edited my question, problem happens when I try to go to route api/routine/tags

Comment: But when I change it to int? null is shown in browser which means that instead of Tags, SingleRoutine is called ?

Comment: Have you debugged and checked which function is called. _routineService.GetAllTags() can also return null.

Comment: Yes, I have but that's not the case  SingleRoutine is being called

Comment: DefaultApi2 --- Do you have any other routes configured? in WebApiconfig or RouteConfig

Answer (score 1):

used Convention-based routing (install nuget package)

add defined following type route on your web api

```
[Route("api/routine/{id}")]
```